# How to concat regclass name with a string in postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create indexes on partition tables using this function. Select query gives me all partitioned tables of test.t and then I iterate over its names and create indexes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.create_index_test() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    f record;
BEGIN
    FOR f IN
        SELECT inhrelid::regclass-- optionally cast to text
        FROM   pg_catalog.pg_inherits
        WHERE  inhparent = 'test.t'::regclass
    loop
    CREATE INDEX concat(f::text,'_geom_index') ON f USING gist (geom);

        -- can do some processing here
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this is giving me error in concat function

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 11:  CREATE INDEX concat(f,'_geom_index') ON f USING gist (geom)...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDL statements doesn't support parametrizations - so you cannot to use variables there.

You need to use dynamic SQL - `EXECUTE` statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.create_index_test() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN
     SELECT inhrelid::regclass AS fullpath, c.relname
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_inherits
            JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = inhrelid
      WHERE  inhparent = 'test.t'::regclass
  LOOP
    EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE INDEX %I ON %s USING gist(geom)', 
                   r.relname || '_geom_index',
                   r.fullpath);

    -- the index name is optional in postgres, so it can be simplified
    -- EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE INDEX ON %s USING gist(geom)',
    --               r.fullpath);
    -- can do some processing here
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: It's giving syntax error CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE INDEX "(ec_vector_v3_temp.ec_1_nam_7)_geom_index" ON f USING gist (geom)".

Comment: @user1298426 - I have not an idea how to can get parenthesis in the name. But there is an error in you idea - you cannot to concat qualified name with any string, The cast to regclass can produce qualified name in some cases. So you need original only relation name too. I updated my code.